# Matrix of rotation and symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra

In orthonormal cordinate system $K:Oe_{1}e_{2}e_{3} $( where all 3 e's are vectors)  ,Given a line $g : {x=1+k,y=0,z=k}$ find how is represented $\phi$ where $\phi$ = $X_{g}(\theta)Y_{\alpha}$ (X,Y are just random letters) which represents rotation around g with angle $\theta$=60 degrees and plane symmetry $\alpha$ passing through O(0,0,0).Now,I  understand for the rotation I have to use the common long formulas but for the second part with the symmetry by what do I have to multiply?Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little bit

Comment: Yeah we are given g and we want to rotate around g with angle 60 degrees and then we have plane symmetry where "a" is  plane,however I can't also understand what do they mean by this symmetry and that is what I am asking,any suggestions?

Comment: If one can rotate the line to the $z$-axis via rotation matrix $R$, and we use $S(\theta)$ to denote rotation around the $z$-axis by $\theta$, then rotation about the given line by $\theta$ is given by $R^{-1}S(\theta)R$. This yields two possible matrices depending on how the original line is oriented. Does this answer your question? It's difficult to figure out what you're saying.

Comment: @Silverser I can make sense out of what transformation you're describing, but I still don't understand what your question is.  Which "common long formulas" are you referring to?  Are you asking for the *matrix representation* of $Y_\alpha$?  Are you applying these transformations using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations)?

Comment: @whacka we choose the positive direction.

Comment: My question is that I have to find 2 matrices one for rotation and one for symmetry but I can't understand how can I find the second matrix.I know how to find a symmetry by a given plane in the form Ax+By+Cz+D

Comment: Are you applying these transformations using homogeneous coordinates?  See my link above

Comment: @Silverser the fact that $\alpha$ passes through the origin just means that $D = 0$.  The best you can do is find a formula in terms of $A,B,$ and $C$.

Comment: @Silverser There is no "positive direction" for an arbitrary line in space. I also don't understand what your second question is. Do you just want the plane through the origin that the rotation fixes? Then just say so. You're stringing words together certainly, but you have to string them together in such a way that we'll understand what you're talking about.